# Php code error with hosting

Tags: phpmyadmin

I am facing problem in my php page, problem is that when I add the code to connect and insert query the data are not stored in database and also the HTML code are not executed ,only the blank screen appear after I click the submit button, 
 But 
All this problem I am facing is when I upload and enter the correct username password, when I run it in camp server all workd in an exact way and also the data is stored in database.

Comment: It would help if we had some code examples to look at, Basically what are you doing.

Comment: I am creating a contact from ,the details are stored in variables but ,not stored in database and also the code for navbar and footer are not shown only the blank screen when I click on submit button, and this issue is when I host that page, when I removed the connection code then everything works as it should